# Using a macro for fstream file input as part of a class

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I have a class that processes a file, and as part of the constructor with one argument I want to input a file using `fstream`.

I basically want it do something like this

```
class someClass{
   public:
      someClass(char * FILENAME)
      {   
          fstream fileToProcess;
          fileToProcess.open(<FILENAME>, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
      }
};
```

I want to pass the filename in as an argument to the class constructor, and then the `class someClass` will access it with `fstream`.

Comment: Surely you mean, `fileToProcess.open (FILENAME, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);`

Are you going to close `fileToProcess` in the `dtor`?

But as @aJ asks... *What is your question*?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: `fstream` closes itself when it goes out of scope.  So, as written, it will go out of scope at the end of the constructor.

Comment: @rcollyer: Of course it does! I should have looked more carefully!

Comment: @rcollyer: Seems a shame not to do anything with the file having gone to the trouble of opening it, though, doesn't it?

Comment: @Johnsyweb:  well, I was assuming that that was just left out of the code posted, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a macro, and you don't have to explicitly call open.

```
using std::fstream;

class someClass
{
    fstream fileToProcess;
    public:
    someClass(char * filename) 
    : fileToProcess(filename, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app) 
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it just the way as you lay it out in the question. Simply pass the string given to the constructor on to the fstream's `open()` method:

```
someClass(const char *filename)
{   
    fstream fileToProcess;
    fileToProcess.open(filename, ...);
}
```